# SF novel in which the presidency of the world depends on your IQ score

Tags: story-identification, novel

A friend is trying to identify a science fiction novel (not a short story) which he read no later than 1980 — more likely in the '60s or '70s. The thing he remembers is that the presidency of the world is dependant on one's IQ score.

He is very clear that it was a novel, so it is not a misremembering of (say) Harrison Bergeron.

Comment: Depends in what way? World president has highest IQ , lowest IQ, most average IQ, or what?

Comment: Reminiscent of the film [_Idiocracy_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175521/58193) that was asked about before.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - yes. Though that's a recent film, but maybe there was some inspiration.

Comment: Were people ranked with shapes and colors? Black for unrated, white star at top? Did the protagonist go from bottom to top?

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents - that is an oddly specific question. Did you have something in mind?

Comment: There's a short story by Mack Reynolds, "Generation Gap," in which a trio of young radicals are organizing and leading a rebellion to overthrow the current government of the USA in favor of having the high-level jobs go to the persons with the highest computer-tested scores. (I don't think it was called "IQ," though -- a more general measure of administrative ability, or some such.) At the end of the story, it turns out that under the new rules, the new President is a kid maybe 13 or 14 years old who aced the tests and tells the rebel leaders they aren't needed in his new administration.

Comment: @user14111 Well in our world it certainly isn't the highest IQ.

Comment: @FrancisDavey I was thinking of *World Out of Mind* (1953) by J. T. McIntosh which I had identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48031/14593)

Comment: In this day and age that seems *extremely* fantastical.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents Oddly enough, I was reminded of a *different* story by J.T. McIntosh, apparently not set in the same future world, but I don't think it actually had the test scores equate to "Congratulations, you are automatically our next President!" I don't think I've ever read *World Out of Mind.* My thought was of "Immortality . . . for Some," which was later expanded (rather poorly) into a paperback novel called *Flight from Rebirth.*

Answer (score 5):

This could be *The World of Ā* (later published as *The World of Null-A*, spelling out the pronunciation of the "Ā" glyph), by A. E. van Vogt.  It was serialized in 1945 and first published as a novel in 1948.

The plot summary, per [Wikipedia](http://The_World_of_Null):

> Gilbert Gosseyn (pronounced *go sane*), a man living in an apparent utopia where those with superior understanding and mental control rule the rest of humanity, wants to be tested by **the giant Machine that determines such superiority**. However, he finds that his memories are false. In his search for his real identity, he discovers that he has extra bodies that are activated when he dies (so that, in a sense, he cannot be killed), that a galactic society of humans exists outside the Solar system, a large interstellar empire wishes to conquer both the Earth and Venus (inhabited by masters of non-Aristotelian logic), and he has extra brain matter that, when properly trained, can allow him to move matter with his mind.

The Games Machine mentioned in the summary is responsible for determining which people are intellectually advanced enough to receive important positions (including the presidency of Earth) or to be allowed to settle on Venus.

Answer (score -1):

It may be [Beyond this Horizon by Heinlein.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_This_Horizon)

> The story's protagonist, Hamilton Felix (surname first), is the archetypal übermensch. Felix is the penultimate step in a "star line" designed to breed for the highest-quality human characteristics. However, he lacks eidetic memory, which disqualifies him for what many consider to be humanity's most important occupation: that of an "encyclopedic synthesist", one who analyzes the sum total of human knowledge for untapped potential. As such, he finds his life—and the society he lives in—to be enjoyable but meaningless. However, when one of these synthesists seeks him out, inquiring when he plans to continue his line, he finds himself drawn into an adventure which not only gives him purpose but convinces him that his society is worth saving after all.

Comment: What elements of this book match the question? Is there even a president in it?